# add custom boxshadow to Flutter card

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I've implemented cards in a Flutter app. I need a custom `BoxShadow` for every card. How can this be done?

What I've tried so far is to add the `BoxShadow` property to the `Card()` constructor, which is not working...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The [Card](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Card-class.html) Widget doesn't have decoration property so you need to make a card inside a [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and then apply the [BoxShadow](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html) to the Container,

**Sample** :

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Card(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Icon(
            Icons.refresh,
            size: 150.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
            blurRadius: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Another thing I want is, Margin around the Heading Text, so that there's gap between subtitle and Heading, Can you help me with it?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean but if you want to add some margins you can easily add this to the Container :
`margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)`

Comment: I'm using this.

Comment: The linter will complain about using the `new` keyword

Answer (score 20):

Simply wrap the card in a container for applying shadow to card widget by obtaining boxShadow property.

```
new Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.5),
        blurRadius: 20.0, // soften the shadow
        spreadRadius: 0.0, //extend the shadow
        offset: Offset(
          5.0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
          5.0, // Move to bottom 10 Vertically
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 18):

See the Card widget

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFdde0e3),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      elevation:5,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

When talk about shadows mainly the appearance of the shadow can be changed by tweaking `blurness` and `color`.

So you can do something like this without writing extra lines of code.

```
Card(
  elevation: 4,  // Change this 
  shadowColor: Colors.black12,  // Change this 
  child: Center(child: Text('Hey, dude.')),
),
```

Comment: The `elevation` and `shadowColor` only work when you want the shadow effect applied without offset and blur effect. `offset` and `blurRadius` can be defined in the `BoxShadow` object, which can't be achieved by tweaking these two parameters.

Answer (score -2):

Use `elevation`

```
Card(elevation: 10, child: theWidget),
```