# How can I add shadow to the widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, shadow

How can I add shadow to the widget like in the picture below?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173205/how-can-put-image-inside-the-image-in-flutter/52178364#52178364) is my current widget code.

[image: Image with shadow]

Comment: take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600394/4511702)

Comment: you can use stack

Comment: Wrap your widget with Material() widget and give elevation: 10.0

Answer (score 625):

Check out [BoxShadow](//api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html) and [BoxDecoration](//api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)

A `Container` can take a `BoxDecoration` (going off of the code you had originally posted) which takes a `boxShadow`

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 100, right: 30, bottom: 50),
  height: double.infinity,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Great answer - tnx!
How would you have the ripple effect over the button? currently it's rippling under the button.

Comment: It's better to use `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)` if every border is same.

Comment: @nitzanwe you can wrap a widget in `InkWell` widget to get ripple effect on tapping.

Comment: The link you mentioned is not working. Changing the domain from flutter.io to flutter.dev works

Answer (score 150):

#### Screenshot:

[image]

---

- ##### Using `BoxShadow` (more customizations):

  ```dart
  Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.teal,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.red,
          blurRadius: 4,
          offset: Offset(4, 8), // Shadow position
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `PhysicalModel`:

  ```dart
  PhysicalModel(
    color: Colors.teal,
    elevation: 8,
    shadowColor: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    child: SizedBox.square(dimension: 100),
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `Card`:

  ```dart
  Card(
    elevation: 8,
    shadowColor: Colors.red,
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.teal,
    ),
  )
  ```
- ##### Using `Material`:

  ```dart
  Material(
    elevation: 8,
    color: Colors.teal,
    shadowColor: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    child: SizedBox.square(dimension: 100),
  )
  ```

Answer (score 121):

Use `BoxDecoration` with `BoxShadow`.

Here is a visual demo manipulating the following options:

- opacity
- x offset
- y offset
- blur radius
- spread radius

The animated gif doesn't do so well with colors. You can try it yourself on a device.

[image]

Here is the full code for that demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ShadowDemo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShadowDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShadowDemoState createState() => _ShadowDemoState();
}

class _ShadowDemoState extends State<ShadowDemo> {
  var _image = NetworkImage('https://placebear.com/300/300');

  var _opacity = 1.0;
  var _xOffset = 0.0;
  var _yOffset = 0.0;
  var _blurRadius = 0.0;
  var _spreadRadius = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child:
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFF0099EE),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, _opacity),
                  offset: Offset(_xOffset, _yOffset),
                  blurRadius: _blurRadius,
                  spreadRadius: _spreadRadius,
                )
              ],
            ),
            child: Image(image:_image, width: 100, height: 100,),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Spacer(),
                Slider(
                  value: _opacity,
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 1.0,
                  onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  {
                    setState(() => _opacity = newValue)
                  },
                ),
                Slider(
                  value: _xOffset,
                  min: -100,
                  max: 100,
                  onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  {
                    setState(() => _xOffset = newValue)
                  },
                ),
                Slider(
                  value: _yOffset,
                  min: -100,
                  max: 100,
                  onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  {
                    setState(() => _yOffset = newValue)
                  },
                ),
                Slider(
                  value: _blurRadius,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  {
                    setState(() => _blurRadius = newValue)
                  },
                ),
                Slider(
                  value: _spreadRadius,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  onChanged: (newValue) =>
                  {
                    setState(() => _spreadRadius = newValue)
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

A Container can take a `BoxDecoration` (going off of the code you had originally posted) which takes a `boxShadow`:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
        ),
    ],
),
```

Comment: It seems like I already mentioned these attributes in [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58510302/6618622).

Answer (score 12):

**PhysicalModel** will help you to give it elevation shadow.

```
 Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
            Container(
              child: PhysicalModel(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.blue,
                elevation: 18,
                shadowColor: Colors.red,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
            Container(
              child: PhysicalShape(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shadowColor: Colors.red,
                elevation: 18,
                clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(shape: CircleBorder()),
                child: Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Use Material with shadowColor inside Container like this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Color(0xffA22447).withOpacity(.05),
            offset: Offset(0, 0),
            blurRadius: 20,
            spreadRadius: 3)
      ]),
  child: Material(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
    elevation: 5,
    shadowColor: Color(0xffA22447).withOpacity(.05),
    color: Color(0xFFF7F7F7),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 8):

this is how I did it

```
    Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        blurRadius: 2.0, // has the effect of softening the shadow
        spreadRadius: 2.0, // has the effect of extending the shadow
        offset: Offset(
          5.0, // horizontal, move right 10
          5.0, // vertical, move down 10
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  child: Container( 
       color: Colors.white, //in your example it's blue, pink etc..
       child: //your content
  )
```

Answer (score 5):

The given answers do the trick for outer shadow i.e. around the widget. I wanted a shadow on the widget which is inside the boundaries and according to the [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18636) there is no inset attribute in ShadowBox yet.
My workaround was to add a layer of widget with a gradient using the stack widget so that it looks like the widget itself has the shadows. You must use the mediaQuery for dimensions otherwise the layout will be messed up on different devices.
Here's a sample of code for better understanding:

```
Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage("assets/sampleFaces/makeup.jpeg"),
                    // fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                height: 350.0,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                    end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
                      Colors.black54,
                    ],
                    stops: [0.95, 5.0],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 5):

Before you start reinventing the wheel with one of these answers, check out the [Material Card widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html). It also allows you to define a global style via the app theme directly:

[image: example]

Answer (score 4):

```
class ShadowContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  ShadowContainer({
    Key key,
    this.margin = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 8),
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    this.circular = 4,
    this.shadowColor = const Color.fromARGB(
        128, 158, 158, 158), //Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
    this.spreadRadius = 1,
    this.blurRadius = 3,
    this.offset = const Offset(0, 1),
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final double circular;
  final Color shadowColor;
  final double spreadRadius;
  final double blurRadius;
  final Offset offset;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: margin,
      padding: padding,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(circular),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: shadowColor,
            spreadRadius: spreadRadius,
            blurRadius: blurRadius,
            offset: offset,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is sufficient if you wrap a `Card` around the `Widget` and play a bit with the `elevation` prop.

I use this trick to make my `ListTile` look nicer in `Lists`.

For your code it could look like this:

```dart
return Card(
   elevation: 3, // PLAY WITH THIS VALUE 
   child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
         // ... MORE OF YOUR CODE 
      ],
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

To add shadow to an any widget in flutter, You can just wrap that widget with **Container** and set following properties:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 2,
        blurRadius: 5,
        offset: Offset(0, 3),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: YourWidget(), // Replace YourWidget with your desired widget
);
```

Happy Fluttering!

Comment: This causes the entire container to be covered with 50% gray, it's not the right solution.

Comment: You can manage shadow with given properties. @LukeHutchison Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Material Design spec inside Flutter, you can use a helper `kElevationToShadow` to create shadows that match the `elevation` property used in other Material components.

You can see the documentation for this property here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/kElevationToShadow-constant.html

The following elevations have defined shadows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 24

Example with a `Container`:

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[8],
  ),
)
```

This is an easy way to add shadows that match the Material specifications, the bigger the elevation the deeper the shadow, so you can play with this value until it fits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.purple,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color:  Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.3),
        blurRadius: 4,
        offset: Offset(6, 5), // Shadow position
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: RadialGradient(
                            center: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
                            focalRadius: 5,
                            focal: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
                            colors: [
                              Themes.primaryColorDark.withOpacity(0.5),
                              Themes.primaryColorDark.withOpacity(0.2),
                            ],
                            stops: [0.9, 0.0],
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: MyColors.whiteColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 2),
                blurRadius: 40,
                color: Colors.blue.secondary,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child....
```

)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your widget into container and give box shadow list to it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30913201)

Comment: Correct, but too vague. Add the code, so that people can basically just copy it into their own code and it'll work! From there, they can personalize it as they want. See below upvoted answer for an excellent example.