# How can I translate a button border in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, layout, widget

I've started to learn flutter a little while ago and I'm really enjoying it!
Currently I'am trying to develop a button like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFAFS.png), but I don't know where to start, or which widgets to use. I'am a front-end developer and it's being really hard to imagine other ways to describe a style than the way we do in css, so any tips or learning will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As far as  I know, you can't translate a border but you can use a `Stack` widget and have a `Container` behind (first child) filled with the orange color and rounded corners, then the second child can be an `OutlineButton` filled with transparent color and has grey borders with rounded corners and `Text` as a child.
It should work just like z-index in CSS but with a transparent child in front.
You can set the `Container` place using `Positioned` wiget.

Comment: Its similar to css, here you can achieve by using `BoxDecoration` and `BoxShadow`  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786514/13625305) also check out examples on [flutter.dev](https://www.flutter.dev/)