# Flutter, overflow shadows

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to somehow draw the shadow of the container ignoring the parent's constraints? margin is not suitable because this increases the spacing between widgets.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786514/10285344

Comment: Thanks for providing a translation, it seems however identical to online translations. If you cannot fluently communicate in English then this might not be the right community for you. The Russion version is not considered helpful additional information here and it seems to imply that you do not trust your English skills.