# How to add bottom elevation to a container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, shadow

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227846/how-can-i-add-shadow-to-the-widget-in-flutter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600056/add-custom-boxshadow-to-flutter-card/49600394#49600394) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333105/flutter-add-box-shadow-to-a-transparent-container) but they don't answer my question. I need elevation on my `Container` *just* below it, not all around it.

Here's what I have as of now:

[image: container with shadow]

My goal at the end is to eliminate the shadow at the top of the days of the week.

I use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55833281/10808802) answer to achieve that shadow effect on my `Container` but I don't want it all the way around, just on the bottom with the rounded corners and not on the top. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `ClipRRect` to remove shadow effects and add bottom `margin` to `Container` to overcome `ClipRRect` at bottom only to show shadow effect.

**Example:**

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0), //Same as `blurRadius` i guess
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0), //(x,y)
                    blurRadius: 6.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: As of October 2022, Material widget implements a shape property that enables you to define the shape of the widget according to your child. This way, you don't need that much parkour to make it work.

Answer (score 154):

In my option the best way is to add Material() over the widget you are currently using.

```
return Material(
       elevation: 20,
       child: Container(),
       );
```

Comment: It's great but it won't work correctly if you also want to change Container shape. If so, use solution from the accepted answer.

Comment: You can also add the same custom shape to Material

Comment: This does not work if implemented in Carousel.

Comment: This is actually not a correct solution, it is not adding shadow only to bottom of Container as questioned, but to all sides.

Answer (score 61):

If you only want to add a shadow then `BoxDecoration` combined with `BoxShadow` will do the job

```
...
...
body: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                blurRadius: 2.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
            )
        ],
    ),
    child: Container(width: 100, height: 50) // child widget, replace with your own
),
...
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 42):

- #### Using `Card`

  [image]

  ```dart
  Card(
    elevation: 8,
    shadowColor: Colors.blue,
    child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.white),
  )
  ```
- #### Using `DecoratedBox`

  [image]

  ```dart
  DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.blue,
          blurRadius: 8,
          spreadRadius: 4,
          offset: Offset(0, 10),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.white),
  )
  ```
- #### Using `PhysicalModel`

  [image]

  ```dart
  PhysicalModel(
    color: Colors.white,
    elevation: 8,
    shadowColor: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    child: Container(width: 100, height: 100),
  )
  ```

Answer (score 17):

Use `Material` and must use `borderRadius:` same for `Container()` and `Material()`

```
Material(
                elevation: 5,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: _width / 1.1,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(50))),
                ),
              ),
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
return PhysicalModel(
         elevation: 20,
         child: Container(),
       );
```

Know more about [PhysicalModel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PhysicalModel-class.html) in Flutter Docs.

Comment: Its also a good solution instead of shadows +1

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep using `Container`. You can use the `boxShadow` in the `BoxDecoration` **with the helper global variable `kElevationToShadow`.**

To only show shadow at the bottom, you can use the `ClipRRect` widget.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16)),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[4],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no `elevation` property for `Container`, you need to use other `Widget` such as `Card`, but if you really do want to give `Container` an `elevation` property, you could take a look at [division](https://pub.dev/packages/division) and watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcq8AbVyMbk) about using that package.

Division: Simple to use yet powerfull style widgets with syntax inspired by CSS. ##

Comment: you can use a container with a BoxDecoration to make an elevation shadow tho

Answer (score 1):

```
child: Container(
                  height: Get.height/4,
                  width: Get.width/1.1,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: UIDataColors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    border: Border.all(color: UIDataColors.white),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        blurRadius: 2.0,
                        spreadRadius: 0.0,
                        offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                ],
              ),


              //color: UIDataColors.white,

            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Card as a parent to your widget and use the elevation property of Card.