# Card elevation shadow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

my card eleveation shadow is only showing in the bottom . How can I set a shadow for 4 sides or corners of the card .

Thank you.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600056/add-custom-boxshadow-to-flutter-card#:~:text=The%20Card%20Widget%20doesn%27t%20have%20decoration%20property%20so%20you%20need%20to%20make%20a%20card%20inside%20a%20Container%20and%20then%20apply%20the%20BoxShadow%20to%20the%20Container%2C) might help. Already answered

Answer (score 0):

increase your blur radius property will give shadow for 4 sides

```
boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow (
          color: light.withOpacity(0.6),
          blurRadius: 7.0,
          spreadRadius: 2
          ),
        ],
```